# Meeting reminders disappear when I accept meetings

Tags: microsoft-outlook, reminder

I'm running Outlook 2016, Windows 10.

- Whenever I accept a meeting from ANY of my clients (multiple companies), the reminders get turned off in the calendar
- I have checked, they have sent a reminder and it shows up on others' calendars
- I reloaded my Outlook profile, still happens
- I have a 15-minute calendar reminder default set on my calendar and the reminder shows up for any invitations I send
- Wanted the other person to know they're not alone - and when you're an independent consultant like I am, I can't just be missing meetings!

Comment: Same problem.  Have you been able to resolve it?

Comment: Same problem. I find it strange you can get weather in your calendar but getting a reminder is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem that has only recently occurred? If so, what specific operations did you do before this problem occurred?

Here are suggestions you can try:

1. Go to File > Options > Mail > Send Messages > Uncheck "Delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding."
2. Try creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile and see if there is any difference.